# Can we use multi level Logical Grouping in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am looking for a query in laravel as

```sql
select * from `itrs` 
where (
  (
    `master_type_id` = ? 
    or `master_type_id` = ?
  ) 
  or `due_date` < ?
) 
and `assigned_to` = ?
```

but getting query

```sql
select * from `itrs` 
where (
  `master_type_id` = ? 
  or `master_type_id` = ? 
  and `due_date` < ?
) 
and `assigned_to` = ?
```

from below code

```php
$ItrDays = Itr::where(function($q) {
    $q->where('master_type_id', 'Urgent ITR')
      ->orWhere('master_type_id', 'One time ITR');
})->orWhere(function($q) {
    $q->where('due_date', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(10));
});
    
$ItrDays->when($admin == 0, function ($q) {
    return $q->where('assigned_to',Auth()->user()->id);
});

dd($admin . $ItrDays->toSql());
```

So is it possible to have multi-level grouping? There is no reference in laravel doc , so if any expert knows about it.
Note : Its Laravel 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, we can use closure inside other closure as below.

Posting an answer if it helps anyone.

```
$ItrDaysList = Itr::where(function ($q) {
                        $q->where('due_date', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(10))
                            ->orWhere(function($q2){
                                $q2->where('master_type_id', 'Urgent ITR')
                                    ->orWhere('master_type_id', 'One time ITR');
                            });
                    });
                $ItrDaysList->when($admin == 0, function ($q) {
                            return $q->where('assigned_to',Auth()->user()->id);
                        });
                $ItrDaysList = $ItrDaysList->get();
```